# Where to use C++ today?

Tags: java, c++, python, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason to use C++ instead of C, Perl, Python, etc.?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29109/is-there-any-reason-to-use-c-instead-of-c-perl-python-etc)
>   [When to use C over C++, and C++ over C?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113295/when-to-use-c-over-c-and-c-over-c)

I am going to enter university next fall in computer sciences, but have been programming already for a few years.  I am currently doing web application development.  I use Python and Java mainly.

I also know C++, but never really pacticed it because everytime I think of a project, there seems to be a language that is better suited for the job than C++.  For example, Java seems to give the same result as C++, but in a more productive way (even performance-wise, Java is not far behind C++).  Not to mention that the Java library is much greater than the C++ one.  This makes me wonder where, in the world of web development, could I use C++ and get an advantage that other languages won't give me?  I currently believe that it would be as an add-on to a language like Java or Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there any reason to use C++ instead of C, Perl, Python, etc.?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29109/is-there-any-reason-to-use-c-instead-of-c-perl-python-etc) - Related: [When to use C over C++, and C++ over C?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113295/when-to-use-c-over-c-and-c-over-c)

Comment: If you want an advantage over languages like Java or Ruby, you might [try something like Lisp.](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html)  In my opinion, C++ is too verbose to provide any competitive advantage over those other languages.

Comment: A lot of government contracting and defense work. Of course you'll probably also use Solaris 10, IRIX, and IBM AIX.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the main Java VM implementation ([HotSpot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot)) is written in C++. This language is still very used mainly for performance and memory issue I think, and because there are still a lot of C and C++ developers. You can find [here](//www.stroustrup.com/applications.html) some application made in C++.

C++ can use C method that are low level, it can be usefull for some application. I don't know if you can write easily a driver in Java for example.

It is also used for creating GUI or games with Qt and SDL.

So C++ is still a good language that can't be totally replaced with Python or Java.

Answer (score 1):

In embedded system development, C and C++ are widely used. We can say that C is industry standart for embedded development. You can easily find a compiler for nearly all micro-controllers. There are also lots of computer program/tool written in C/C++. Games and 3D designing softwares (CAD,CAM) also prefer C++.

Answer (score 1):

There are whole industries (games, high-perf garphics, etc) where C++ is the dominant language today and likely to stay dominant for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Google does lots of work in C++.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754301/what-programming-language-is-google-written-in

Anywhere you go, where you need performance, C and C++ are the way to go.